# ORA-04091: table name is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have trigger like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER orders_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON orders
   FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
   v_type number;

BEGIN
   SELECT type
   INTO v_type
   FROM orders
   WHERE id = :new.parent_id;

   -- do sth with v_type
END;
```

I receive an error message as follows:

> ORA-04091: table name is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

I don't update any rows in *orders* table, so is any workaround for this?
I need only select type of row representing parent of new record and use this value in update of another table.

Comment: Why do you want to do that in a trigger; can't the insert supply the correct type itself, querying the table itself if necessary?

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. Please read this other [discussion](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5432/what-are-the-causes-and-solutions-for-mutating-table-errors) on how to avoid the error.

Answer (score 0):

You should use PRAGMA_AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION to retrieve type column in another session and not get error ora-04091:

create a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SF_GETTYPE (pParent_id NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
IS
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
    v_type number;          
BEGIN
    SELECT type
    INTO v_type
    FROM orders
    WHERE id = pParent_id;

    RETURN v_type;
END;
```

Modify trigger to use function SF_GETTYPE :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER orders_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON orders
   FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
   v_type number;

BEGIN
   v_type := SF_GETTYPE(:new.parent_id);
   -- do sth with v_type
END;
```

Regards

Comment: You may add that there's no need to select the type from the orders table since it's already available in :new.type

Comment: He needs the column type of another row. :new.type refers to the current row.